# an instance of :class:`plotly.graph_objs.Bar`

Tags: pandas, plotly-python

Plotting Pandas in Plotly Subplots throwing this error

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(worldData_2, x='TotalCases', y='Country', orientation='h'),row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(worldData_2, x='TotalDeaths', y='Country', orientation='h'),row=1, col=2)
fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder='total ascending')
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="COVID19", showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

Error, Whats the error

```
2644 The first argument to the plotly.graph_objs.Bar
   2645 constructor must be a dict or
-> 2646 an instance of :class:`plotly.graph_objs.Bar`"""
   2647             )
   2648 

ValueError: The first argument to the plotly.graph_objs.Bar 
constructor must be a dict or 
an instance of :class:`plotly.graph_objs.Bar`
```

How to pass the Pandas DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

From the plotly docs on [go.Bar](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Bar.html) the first positional argument is:

> arg – dict of properties compatible with this constructor or an instance of plotly.graph_objects.Bar

This is where the error message comes from, as a DataFrame is unexpected.

This is unlike [px.Bar](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar.html#plotly-express-bar) which accepts a DataFrame as an argument:

> data_frame (DataFrame or array-like or dict) – This argument needs to be passed for column names (and not keyword names) to be used. Array-like and dict are tranformed internally to a pandas DataFrame. Optional: if missing, a DataFrame gets constructed under the hood using the other arguments.

---

Since `go.Bar` only accepts sets of coordinates for the `x` and `y` parameters, pass the `Series` to `x` and `y` instead.

Something like:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=worldData_2['TotalCases'], y=worldData_2['Country'],
           orientation='h'),
    row=1, col=1
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=worldData_2['TotalDeaths'], y=worldData_2['Country'],
           orientation='h'),
    row=1, col=2
)
fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder='total ascending')
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="COVID19", showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```